# Adding observations to panel in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a panel data from year `t1` to `t2`. Some individuals enter the sample after `t1` and/or exit the sample before `t2`. For efficiency (large sample), **the dataset only contains rows for years when individuals are observed.**

I want to add a new observation per individual, containing the **year after** an individual left the sample. So, if someone left in, say 2003, I want the new observation to contain the individual's id and the value `2004` in the year variable. Every other variable in that observation should be missing.

This is my approach, using a sample dataset:

```
webuse nlswork, clear

* Here goes plenty of lines of codes modifying the dataset ... for generality *

timer on 1

preserve
keep id year
bysort id (year) : keep if _n == _N
replace year = year + 1
save temp.dta, replace
restore

append using temp.dta
sort id year
erase temp.dta

timer off 1
timer list
```

I think this might be a bit inefficient, as it includes a preserve/restore, saving/deleting an additional database, and an append, all relatively time-consuming actions. Something like `tsfill, last` would be amazing, but that option doesn't exist. Is anyone aware of a **more efficient** method? The code above includes timer, so anyone can benchmark it against another method.

Comment: The `preserve` / `restore` is not necessary strictly speaking.

Comment: @PearlySpencer you mean by changing the order of dataset loading? That's the case in this example, but in reality I do many stuff with the dataset, before.

Comment: @NickCox updated

Answer (score 1):

I am never that impressed by attempts to save seconds when coding takes minutes. This is more direct than your approach.

```
bysort id (year) : gen byte last = _n == _N 
expand 2 if last 
bysort id (year) : replace year = year + 1 if _n == _N
```

EDIT: You need to loop over the other variables in your dataset to replace their values with missing. For simplicity, I will assume that they are all numeric.

```
bysort id (year) : replace last = _n == _N 
ds id year, not 
quietly foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    replace `v' = . if last 
}
```